# .Net core and role based authorization

Tags: .net, .net-core, roles

I am trying to understand how .Net core role based authorization works. I've read a few tutorial and is still confused. I am sure I have a knowledge gap somewhere that is preventing me from connecting the dots. AFIK we have 3 table, AspNetRoles, which has the roles available, AspNetUsers, the users, and AspNetUserRoles, how we map user to roles. The next thing that has me stump is that in our controller we simply add the authorize attribute like this `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` and then it magically works. I understand we still need to register the identity service in our startup, but then that's it, a lot of the tutorial does not go in depth after this. Is this because the handler and requirement is taken care of by .Net and by simply passing the role it knows to check those 3 tables? I am lost as to how it works because I see that there are the other tables like AspNetRoleClaims and AspNetUserClaims and I am not sure how that factors in.

Comment: How do you authenticate and authorize users in your startup pipeline? JWTs?

Comment: @Henkolicious It looks like we are using user<identity>